# C# TextBox that allows a maximum of one dot

Tags: c#, textbox

**How can I make a [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) in C# to allow a maximum of one `.` (dot)?**

Thus, `abcdef` and `abc.def` would be valid inputs whereas `ab.cd.ef` wouldn't.

By *allow* I mean that the user should not be able to enter a dot if there is already one in the text field.

Java has `DocumentFilter`s for that purpose, is there something similar in C#?

Comment: yes, there are several ways (regex, foreach, string methods) but what have you tried so far?

Comment: are you trying to find a way to validate an e-mail? because that is a very crude method which won't be robust or user friendly.

Comment: @JGreenwell can u show me one way?

Comment: @Claies no, not an e-mail

Comment: I know! @Scriptim you must be validating a floating point number!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is for validating user inputs. You should create a button and tell the user when he is done, press it so that you can check whether there is only one `.` in the string.

Assumptions:

Let your text box be called `tb`. Let your button's `Click` event handler be `BtnOnClick`.

Now we can start to write code. First create the handler:

```
private void BtnOnClick (object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

In the handler, you need to loop through the string and check each character. You can use a `foreach` for this:

```
int dotCount = 0;
string s = tb.Text;
if (s.StartsWith(".")) //starts with .
    //code to handle invalid input
    return;
if (s.EndsWith(".")) //ends with .
    //code to handle invalid input
    return;
foreach (char c in s) {
    if (c == '.') {
        dotCount++;
    }
    if (dotCount >= 2) { //more than two .
        //code to handle invalid input
        return;
    }
}
// if input is valid, this will execute
```

Alternatively, you can use a *query expression*. But I think you are unlikely to know what that is.

```
string s = tb.Text;
if (s.StartsWith(".")) //starts with .
    //code to handle invalid input
    return;
if (s.EndsWith(".")) //ends with .
    //code to handle invalid input
    return;
var query = from character in s
            where character == '.'
            select character;
if (query.Count() > 1) {
    //code to handle invalid input
    return;
}
// if input is valid, this will execute
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo. I corrected it. @AndrewMorton